# Create a true/false boolean data-attribute with JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm creating an element on a website that will appear/disappear after an ajax request is made. The idea is that the ajax will check for a true/false data attribute on the HTML and act accordingly using Javascript.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to toggle that boolean based on if something is defined or not. For example this is what I have right now

```
<c:if test="${not empty custom.input}">
    <aside id="alert" class="row" data-path="//urlhere">
    </aside>
</c:if>
<div data-foo="">
</div>
```

I want to create another data attribute (shown as data-foo in the example) which will be `false` if `${custom.input}` is empty, and then have it set to `true` if `${custom.input}` has input.

How would I do this?

Comment: What's the point? If custom.input is false, the aside element will not be in the page at all, so the data attribute won't exist at all.

Comment: @JBNizet It's for another element outside of the if, I should of specific that. My apologies.

Comment: That said, what's the problem with `data-foo="${custom.input}"`? And why do you use `not empty custom.input` instead of just `custom.input`, if it's supposed to be a boolean?

Comment: @JBNizet That wouldn't really work with what I'm doing as it holds text for the page. Is there not a way to set a true/false if there's input in custom.input?

Comment: So, custom.input is not a boolean, and can thus not be true nor false, as you claim in your question. When do you **actually** want the data attribute to be true or false?

Comment: If custom.input is empty, I want it to be false. If custom.input has data, I want it to be true.

Comment: So, you just want `data-foo="${not empty custom.input}"`.

Comment: @JBNizet That does it. Guess I was misunderstanding what you were saying. Thanks for the help!